# UITextField Shadow like in the AppStore password prompt

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, coding-style, uitextfield

Is it possible (wihout using a background image) to create the same effect as in the AppStore password prompt. (in the UIAlertView) I'm specifically talking about the bevelled border and the shadow in the upper third.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The textfield should be rectangular (no rounded rectangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following code helps?

```
yourAlertTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
yourAlertTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

I suppose you should have textfield font size bigger then 12 to see the effect.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That was not exactly what I was looking for. I suppose I should have mentioned, that I want the textField to be rectangular.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that 'natively'. You have to use bg image or you have to [draw everything in code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). If you look closer to the AppStore password alert you'll see the corners of the text field rectangle rounded :)